# Get angle from three points

Tags: javascript, math

I am working on a little javascript geometry library and need to get the angle ϐ from my points A, B and C. I tried it but it didn't return the right angle.

Here's my code:

*(deleted)*

The script part is in File maths2d on line 32.

Comment: Could you add the code to your question? I suppose no one wants to download any files

Comment: Please post the code, not a link.  There are two angles to be had in a Euclidian plane: theta and 2*pi-theta.  They are easy to calculate using vectors and dot or cross product.  Do a Google search to see what I mean.

Comment: Sorry but the fiddle is bugging because I can't post that much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the angle at A from B to C compute

```
AB = B-A     
AC = C-A     

angleRadians = Math.atan2( AB.x*AC.x + AB.y*AC.y, AB.y*AC.x - AB.x*AC.y )

angleDegrees = angleRadians*180/Math.Pi
```

And yes, there are the dreaded scalar and cross products inside. Or a rotation matrix applied to a vector. To understand this you will need some analytical geometry.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that it returns radians. On the calculator it returned degree.

Comment: On pocket calculators you can switch between radians, degrees and sometimes gon/Neugrad. Most people leave it at degrees since it is more intuitive (in the sense of an acquired taste). But algorithmically/mathematically, radians are natural, thus the instruction set/math libraries default to that and leave the conversion to more intuitive scales to the programmer.